# Google Maps No Route Found on Android device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-install-apk

When using Google maps for navigation in an Android application, the directions are shown in the emulator but when running on the device (signed APK as well), the following message is displayed.

[image]

What could be the reason and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Probably because your pin is in the ocean.

Comment: Are you asking for location permission?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Yes, and location is on still this message is shown.

Comment: @Mihai The pin shows correctly in the emulator.

Comment: Are you using release maps API key or debug one on the signed apk?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga How can I verify that? This app was already published on the store and stopped working a while back only. I tried generating a new key on the Google Cloud Platform and am using that.

Comment: Apparently usage rules have changed. Look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup
For Android apps, you restrict the key to your app's SHA-1 fingerprint and package name.

It seems you have to register billing data to get some free requests.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Could you point me to a link mandating registering billing data? I added app's SHA-1 fingerprint and package name but am still facing the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Click Get Started in the given link. It is meant to enable the APIs and set the biling info. Also in the same page you can find Guide for Existing Users. It has ransitioning tool. There you can find pricing and billing changes.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga The transitioning tool gives an error logging into the account while verifying user credentials.

Comment: That's as much as I could help as I am not currently working with google maps API, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178447/discussion-between-sumit-and-deividas-strioga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we came up with in comments, it probably is due to policy changes using google maps API. In production ready, signed apk, restricted API key should be used. Also, to get some free API requests a billing details must be set. More info and transition at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup